# Add certificate to JAVA > Signer CA through command-line

Tags: java, certificate

I have created a Deployment ruleset for JAVA.
This file is self-signed with a certificate. In order to use this ruleset you need to import the certificate to JAVA > Security > Certificates > Signer CA.

If I do this manually the ruleset works so no problem there.
But I would like to deploy this to all my users with a script.

If I use following script it places the certificate under Trusted Certificates, but I need it under Signer CA in order for it to work.

```
keytool -import -v -file C:\certificate.crt -alias Alias1 -keystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs"  -storepass pwd -noprompt
```

I have searched high and low but can't seem to find a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution! :)
I needed to import it to trusted.cacerts instead of trusted.certs !

It looks like this:

```
keytool -import -v -file C:\certificate.crt -alias Alias1 -keystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.cacerts"  -storepass pwd -noprompt
```

Source: http://symplik.blogspot.be/2013/11/get-rid-of-java-applet-warning-when_3.html